# My elasticache cluster is storing some keys and discarding others

Tags: java, amazon-elasticache

My elasticache is not storing all of the keys it supposed to

I have an elasticache cluster configured and I am using it in my java application to cache values.
The main reason behind this was to reduce ddb calls from the service since it was costing us a fortune.
But even after introducing cache, the read throughput didn't seem to come down as significantly as I expected.
After Putting up cache miss logs in the service, I found out that there are massive cache misses happening.
Which made me think maybe the cache is not populating in the first place, so I put up cache hit logs as well and to my surprise there are cache hit logs as well.
I am a bit confused, either no entries should be there or all entries should be there. how come some entries are populating and some are not.
Note: The TTL for the key is kept 2 days, so no chance of invalidating keys this early.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, there are no exceptions during redis set or get. So no failures

Comment: Did you look at your CloudWatch metrics? I'd specifically look at `DatabaseMemoryUsagePercentage` and `SetBasedCmds` to see if your application is working as expected.

By the way, if you are using ElastiCache for Redis only as a cache in front of your DynamoDB, have you considered using [DAX](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/) instead?